# Determining diffeomorphism

Tags: calculus, analysis, jacobian, diffeomorphism

I have to determine for all  $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, for which the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,$$f(x) = x^3+ax^2 +bx$$ is a diffeomorphism.

This is how far I got:
I know that det $J_f$(Jacobi-matrix) can't be zero. So I tried to find the Jacobi Matrix:
$$J_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i} = 3x^2+ax+b$$
Is that correct? Since it is one dimensional I'm not sure how to calculate the Jacobi-matrix. And how do I find out the determinant? Is it just $3x^2+2ax+b$? And the function is a diffeomorphism as long as the determinant is not zero?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We have $f( \mathbb R)= \mathbb R$. Why ?

Hence $f$ is surjective.

Now you have to determine $a$ and $b$ such that the derivative $f'$ has no zero in $\mathbb R$.

We have $f'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b$. Can you proceed ?

Comment: why the downvote ?????????????????????????